# Separating string and integer using delimiter

Tags: c, scanf, delimiter

Good day,

So currently I have this file and contains: the actual file is like this

```
1,name A. lname2,Das F. Esd3,Frsas A. Casdfre4,Rsadna P. Tsdaas5,Asadla C. Toasdtino6,Aasdel P. Gasdla7,Masda Isable A. Milasdroso8,Niasdkie T. Niasdemus9,Evasdn A. Vasdueva10,Geasdlyn C. Iasdncio11,Aasdr Leasdma12,Neasdio A. Maasdbale
```

I have trouble doing the output, here is my current code

```
printf("\nID\tName\n");    
while(fscanf(load, "%[^,],%[^1-9]", faculty[counter].id, faculty[counter].name)!=EOF) {  
    printf("%s\t%s", faculty[counter].id, faculty[counter].name);
```

[image: output]
and the output goes like this:

```
ID  Name    
1   asdasd    
2   asdas   
3   asdsad4     othername    
5   asdsad   
6   asdasda    
7   sdfsdf    
8   sadsad   
9   asdsad       
10  asdas    
11  asdsad12    asdas       
4,12 has invalid position.
```

the output should be arange:

```
1  ID   Name    
1   asdasd    
2   asdas   
3   asdsad    
4   othername    
5   asdsad   
6   asdasda    
7   sdfsdf    
8   sadsad   
9   asdsad       
10  asdas    
11  asdsad    
12  asdas
```

What could be the problem? This is my first time using such delimiter, and can you please explain what's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Please use proper formatting for the code blocks, the output and the file's content. @Someprogrammerdude was trying to fix it but your edits changed it back. Latest fix applied by Eimantas.

Comment: code fixed, sorry for that

Comment: You're using regular expressions in `fscanf` ;this is not correct, it only understands format  strings.

Comment: If you want to read input like this robustly, using `fscanf`, it can be very, very difficult, especially if the input has weird wrinkles, or if you want to handle input errors gracefully.  In general it's much easier (in the long run) to read input using techniques other than `(f)scanf`.  This seems harder at first, because `*f)scanf` *seems* so convenient, and it's what all beginning textbooks show you as if it's *the* way to do input.  But it's not, and the sooner you can learn about those other techniques, and abandon `(f)scanf`, the happier and more productive you'll be as a C programmer.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Actually, the `scanf` family *does* support a very limited regular-expression-like functionality, using the `%[`...`]` specifier, as shown.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma any idea how can i separate it?

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for the advice, i actually tried to fix this all day, but no luck, i'll try to look at the other techniques, it's that just i'm much familiar with fscanf than any other techniques, and also may take time learning new techniques, it's a school project and i need to rush it

Comment: Can you make a test file with fake names that shows the problem? Also post the complete code that fails. The structure definitions are important too. It is difficult to set a diagnostic without precise data and code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the format to this:

```
printf("\nID\tName\n");    
while (fscanf(load, " %[0-9], %[^0-9]", faculty[counter].id, faculty[counter].name) == 2) {  
    printf("%s\t%s\n", faculty[counter].id, faculty[counter].name);
    ...
    counter++;
}
```

Note that you should also pass the maximum number of characters to store to the destination arrays to avoid potential buffer overflows.

Note however that the sample output posted in the question is inconsistent with the code fragment: you do not output a newline in the `printf` format and confirm there is no newline in the data file, where do the newlines in the output come from?

Can you make a test file with fake names that shows the problem? Also post the complete code that fails. The structure definitions are important too. It is difficult to set a diagnostic without precise data and code.

Comment: only 1 output is displayed with this

Comment: The output you show is inconsistent with the file contents you posted. Is there always a comma after the number? Does the file contain newlines?

Comment: yes, it's like this, there's a comma after the number, but after the lastname, there's no comma, there is no newlines
 1,fistname A. lastname2,firstname F. lastname

i just added some random character because it contains real name, sorry for that

Comment: @JesusEnriqueBuencamino I think you need to fix your input, then.  You said "there's a comma after the number", but the problem seems to be that there is *not* a comma between `2` and `Das F. Esd`.

Comment: sorry for that i again, i will edit the post again, there should be a comma between 2 and Das F

Comment: @JesusEnriqueBuencamino And have you tried your code again?  Now that you've fixed the input, the original code is working fine for me.  So there's sort of no question at this point.

Comment: @SteveSummit the input i posted here is wrong, but my original file is right, and i have changed the input here, and the output is still the same, i have no idea why it's not working for me, still the same output

Comment: i have just find out that my file is the main cause of the problem, when i open the file it looks the same as the original file, but when i replace it, it suddenly works, thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

This is one circumstance where reading with `fscanf` alone can work, but lacks the robustness you can achieve by reading the entire line at once and then parsing the line with either `sscanf` or simply walking a pair of character pointers down the line picking out the `id` and `name` pairs.

To use `fscanf` on the line you have posted as input, you can use the *format specifier* of `"%d,%[^0-9]"` in repeated calls to `fscanf`. (you should provide a *field-width* modifier to prevent against overflow if name is longer than your array size). For example you could do something like the following to obtain each `id` and `name` pair (which are just output in the example below):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXNM = 64 };   /* constant for max characters in name */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int id;
    char name[MAXNM] = "";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each 'id,name' pair (name cannot include digits) */
    while (fscanf (fp, "%d,%63[^0-9]", &id, name) == 2)
            printf ("%3d    %s\n", id, name);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rd_num_name <dat/num_names.txt
  1    name A. lname
  2    Das F. Esd
  3    Frsas A. Casdfre
  4    Rsadna P. Tsdaas
  5    Asadla C. Toasdtino
  6    Aasdel P. Gasdla
  7    Masda Isable A. Milasdroso
  8    Niasdkie T. Niasdemus
  9    Evasdn A. Vasdueva
 10    Geasdlyn C. Iasdncio
 11    Aasdr Leasdma
 12    Neasdio A. Maasdbale
```

If you want to use *line-oriented* input with `fgets` or `getline` to read the entire line and then parse each `id` and `name` from the buffer holding the entire line, you can do something like the following. The benefit of reading the entire line, and then parsing -- is that it decouples the read from the parse allowing you to validate both. Additionally, your read isn't subject to *matching failures* on slight variations of input format.

Here, using `sscanf` and utilizing the `%n` *format specifier* to determine the number of characters consumed by each call to `sscanf`, you can walk a pointer down the line picking out `id` and `name` pairs, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXNM = 64, MAXLN = 512 };   /* max name & line constants */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int id;
    char name[MAXNM] = "",
        line[MAXLN] = "",
        *p = line;          /* pointer to line to walk string */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (line, sizeof line, fp))   /* read each line / validate */
    {
        int offset = 0;                     /* number of char processed  */
        while (sscanf (p, "%d,%63[^0-9]%n", &id, name, &offset) == 2) {
            printf ("%3d    %s\n", id, name);
            p += offset;                    /* advance to next id,name */
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** the output is the same.